# How can I make my controller return JSON back to my template PHTML

Tags: magento2, controllers, phtml, admin-controller

Controller:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\ExampleAdminNewPage\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  /**
   * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
   * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
   */
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
  ) {
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
  }

  /**
   * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
   */
  public function execute()
  {
    /* Create array for return value */
    $response['value1'] = "Value one";
    $response['value2'] = "Value Two";
    $response['value3'] = "Value Three";

    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON); //create Json type return object
    $resultJson->setData($response); // array value set in Json Result Data set

    return $resultJson; // return json object
  }
}
```

Calling from PHTML:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8888/magento2/rest/V1/integration/admin/token', {
            method: 'POST', 
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "username": "admin",
                "password": "admin1@admin.com"
            }),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(token => {
            (function($) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo $block->getUrl('*/product'); ?>",
                    data: dataBody,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader ("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {
                            xhr.overrideMimeType("application/j-son;charset=UTF-8");
                        }
                    },
                    success: function(html) {
                        console.log("success: ", html);
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
        });
```

However, when I try to do this on I can see that the URL is correct but it returns 401 Unauthorized

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/magento2/admin/exampleadminnewpage/product/index/key/bfa7629e0c8323d434158ed68e5dd61f9e0d8ca428f859eb916412c740c89d72/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
```

And I can see this error in the Debug Logs

```
main.DEBUG: Request validation failed for action "Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward\Interceptor" [] []
```

Any Idea what is happening here? I am new to Magento and PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my Controller had the wrong class name.

The file was named Index.php but the class name there says Product...